# Extract a value from a page's function... ¿Without unsafeWindow?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm new at Greasemonkey. I'm trying to create a user script to improve my user experience with a site I often visit.

So I'd like to create a javascript function `f()`. My function requires a value that, according to my quick research and try at understanding the site's structure, only exists inside a javascript function `g()`.

I am not sure of which file holds `g()` on the server, but what I do know is that once the page has finished downloading, `g()` can be used.

I would like to extract the string value from `g()` without executing it (with `g.toString()`).

My question is: how can I access `g()`, without compromising my computer with `unsafeWindow`?
(`window.g` returns `null` inside the Greasemonkey script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `unsafeWindow`. It's really not that evil.

```
var string = unsafeWindow.g.toString();
```

`unsafeWindow` is relatively safe. I have previously discovered a method to access an unrestricted `window` object in GreaseMonkey. Using a specific method, it's possible to read the original code of the Userscript by the affected page. Specific GreaseMonkey functions (`GM_getValue`, ..) cannot be used though: **[Advanced GreaseMonkey: Using constructors/methods/variables at a remote page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804765/how-do-i-use-constructor-of-a-remote-page-to-create-an-object-in-my-greasemonkey/7781016#7781016)**

**EDIT, regarding the title change**
If you fear that `g` is not a function, or that the `toString` method of the function is overwritten, use the following code:

```
//Store unsafeWindow.g in a variable, to reduce the possibly defined 
// __defineGetter__ calls to a minimum.
var g_string = unsafeWindow.g;
if(typeof g_string == "function"){
    g_string = Function.prototype.toString.call(g_string);
}
else g_string = ""; //Reset
```

#### Is it safe?

The previous code is the safest approach, because no methods of `g` are invoked. The GreaseMonkey wrapper also prevents the affected page from reading the script:

```
window.g = function(){}
window.__defineGetter__("g", function(){
    alert(arguments.callee.caller);
});
```

The previous code will not show the real caller, but an useless wrapper function:

```
function SJOWContentBoundary() {
    [native code]
}
```

Comment: @SimonNN Updated answer regarding title change.